# Elasticsearch inline string replace seems to do nothing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

We have some legacy fields in Elastic search index, which cause us some troubles and we would like to perform a  string replace over the whole index.

For instance some old timestamps are stored in format of `2000-01-01T00:00:00.000+0100` but should be stored as `2000-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00`.

I tried to run following query:

```
POST /my_index/_update_by_query
{
    "script":
    {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx._source.timestamp = ctx._source.timestamp.replace('+0100', '+01:00')"
    }
}
```

I run the query within Kibana, but I always get a query timeout - I guess that is not necessarily bad considering the database is huge, however I never see the fields updated.

Is there a way to see the status of such query?

I also tried to create a search query for the update, but with no luck:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*0100",
      "allow_leading_wildcard": true,
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "fields": ["timestamp"]
    }
  }
}
```

Which unfortunately always returns empty set - not sure what might be wrong.

What would be a correct way to achieve such update?

Comment: You should use the `wait_for_completion=false` parameter to run the task in the background, see [here how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66667323/elasticsearch-bulk-update-for-nested-object/66667384#66667384)

Comment: sounds helpful! could you also check the search query? why it wouldn't return any ressults?

Comment: date fields are not analyzed like text fields are, so it's the reason that this kind of query (i.e. wildcard query) works

Comment: How does your mapping look like for that field by the way?

Comment: the mapping is `"timestamp" : { "type" : "date" }` – so is there a way to query these broken fields?

Comment: Why do you say "broken"? If the documents were ingested without errors, it means the value is compliant with the expected date format, i.e. `+0100` is the same as `+01:00`, both are valid syntax for the GMT+1 timezone

Comment: Our java parser requires the timezone being stored in format `+01:00` instead of `+0100`, so I would somehow like to replace this in ES.

Comment: I see you edited the comment - even though both are valid, the java parser refuses to accept them :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this using an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) that you'll use to update your whole index.

First, create the ingest pipeline like below. What it does is detect documents which have a `timestamp` field ending with `+0100` and then updates the timestamp to use the timezone with the correct format.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/fix-tz
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "dissect": {
        "if": "ctx.timestamp.endsWith('+0100')",
        "field": "timestamp",
        "pattern": "%{timestamp}+%{tz}"
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "if": "ctx.tz != null",
        "field": "timestamp",
        "value": "{{timestamp}}+01:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove": {
        "if": "ctx.tz!= null",
        "field": "tz"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, when the pipeline is created, you just have to update your index with it, like this:

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query?pipeline=fix-tz&wait_for_completion=false
```

Once this has run completely, your index should be properly updated.

Comment: Can you also explain how to perform a query like `GET /my_index/_search` for such fields?

Comment: It's not really possible. There is a `script` query but for performance reasons it doesn't allow you to retrieve the raw string from `ctx._source`